# Command DELETE dont work in vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a project that adds and deletes dates , add paragraph have the following code:

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO TMP " _
E " ( diaMes ) VALUES ( " _
& "' " & Tmp7 & "' ) "
```

where tmp7 is date type like dd-mm-yyyy and works perfectly

delete is the following code:

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
dbs.Execute " DELETE * FROM TMP " _
And " where diaMes = # " ​​& tmp7 & " # " ;
```

The problem is that delete only the day to more than 12 ,I understand , If day equals less than 12 is interpreted as mm-dd-yyyy

the tmp7 is a string concatenation string.

How do I force a SQL Pass dd-mm-yyyy ?

Comment: `CDate` will convert your string to a date, assuming it is in a format that can be converted.`Format(YourField, "Short Date")` will convert the date into a dd/MM/yyyy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access uses American Date format, so even when you pass DD/MM/YYYY it will think MM/DD/YYYY. As you clearly see the dates over 12 are understood correctly. Example 13/10/2014 will be understood as 13th October 2014. But 7/10/2014 in our eyes is 7th October 2014, but ambigious to Access so it interprets it as 10th July 2014.

So your trouble could be avoided by formatting it correctly. Try using this,

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
dbs.Execute "DELETE * FROM TMP WHERE diaMes = " & _
            Format(tmp7, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

Comment: Hello, i understand the resolution but give error  (Expected: expression)

Comment: OOPS ! Sorry I seemed to have misplaced the Double quotes. Could you please refer to the edited code?